# DAL executesql parameterized queries

Tags: python, web2py

I've been looking, but I can't find the information I'm looking for anywhere.

How do I use parameterized queries with custom sql using DAL in web2py? For example, I have the following query:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = %s"
```

And I call it like

```
user = db.executesql(sql, username, as_dict=True)
```

which I thought would use parameters for the query, but if I pass "' or 1=1; --;" as the username, the code crashes saying it is invalid SQL.

What is the correct way to use parameterized queries with custom SQL using DAL, as this is obviously not escaping in the way I thought it was?

Thanks,

Travis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `placeholders` parameter:

```
user = db.executesql(sql, placeholders=(username,), as_dict=True)
```

Comment: That's what I am using. Username being passed as the placeholders parameter. On one server the code seems to work fine without crashing, but on a new deploy, the code runs but doesn't escape it.

Comment: @TravisSmith That's probably because each server is using a different driver. Which SQL engine are you using?

Comment: Both servers are using Maria10, but is there something I can run to verify everything is loading up the same and they're using the same driver?

Comment: @TravisSmith You can `print(db._adapter)`

Comment: Thanks, but both servers return:
"pydal.adapters.mysql.MySQLAdapter"

Comment: @TravisSmith Note you must pass the placeholders as a sequencue (a list or a tuple), but you're passing a string. That might cause unexpected behavior becuase a string is itself a sequence of characters. In short, use `placeholders=(username,)` instead of `placeholders=username`.

Comment: Updating it to be:
executesql(sql, (username,), as_dict=True)

Has the same problem, unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Turns out the PyMySQL version has a bug in it (https://github.com/web2py/web2py/issues/1438) that caused this behaviour. Updating it to 0.7.11 fixed the issue.

Comment: @TravisSmith Great ;)